# Insert selected data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
Code | Description
Ab | Sample
Cd | Sample1
De | Sample2
Fg | Sample3
Hi | Sample4
Jk | Sample5
```

I have sample data which is inserted into another table but selected data only.
For example: Insert only code "ab" ,"fg" and "jk" from table1 into another table in one query.

Would it be possible?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can achieve this using below query.

```
Insert into table2(Code, Description)
Select Code, Description from table1 where Code in('ab' ,'fg','jk')
```